# Error while configuring local repository in Git in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, git, github, repository

This may sound too amateur but as a whole i want to configure my Git repository and move my code from eclipse to Github.

So i checked out a couple of video tutorials and applied the steps but none of them seems to work in my case. This is what i did.
1) Right click on the project > Team > Share Project > Select Git > and then this window comes 
[image]

now when i try to create my repository by clicking on create button> fill the parent directory and the name and click finish. Nothing really happens and i am redirected to the same previous window, without the repository column loaded.
Can anyone help me out of this. 
[image]
First i thought it to be a Eclipse version issue, earlier i tried on Luna, also after installing Juno its the same issue.

Help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you return to previous window, is the button labelled Next> not enabled?

Comment: No, it is the exact replica of the first screenshot, after clicking finish and entering Parent Directory and the name.

Comment: Any help on this issue ?